# Ошибка вызова конструктора из внутри тега <script>

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, ооп, конструктор, webpack2

Собираю проект на webpack.

Вот такой код работает:

*js:*

```
function Console() {
  console.log(123);
}

var a = Console();
```

*html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

А вот такой - нет:

*js:*

```
function Console() {
  console.log(123);
}
```

*html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
    var a = new Console();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Во втором случае в консоль падает вот такая ошибка:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined

Два очень простых (но не для меня) вопроса - почему в консоль валится ошибка и как сделать так, чтобы работало?

Comment: Для начала нужно написать что за ошибка, что в тексте, на какую строку указывает и т.д.

Comment: На самом деле оба варианта отлично работают

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если запустить, то видно что во втором варианте не определяется функция `Console`

Comment: @Grundy но второй вариант падает в ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: Console is not defined`

Comment: @Илья неа, у тебя что-то либо с путями, либо ты чего-то не сказал. Текущий вариант вполне рабочий

Comment: А не в том ли проблема, что в момент выполнения содержимого тега `<script>` js файл с этой функцией еще не загружен?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а строгий режим может на это влиять? Я вебпаком собираю файл

Comment: @AntonShchyrov однако он подключен выше и должен соответственно загрузится раньше

Comment: Наверное проблема с областями видимости связана. Скорее всего при сборке Console находится в какой-то локальной области. И здесь из скрипта не видна. Попробуйте объявить функцию Console как window.Console = function() { console.log( 'aaa' ) }, а вызов можно не менять.

Comment: ну если вебпаком, тогда понятно. Посмотри скомпилированный код, он каждый файл рассматривает как модуль, и, как следствие, все содержимое этого файла оборачивает в самовызывающуюся функцию

Comment: @Grundy да, действительно в этом проблема. Перенес код в отельный файл - все работает. Но как мне собрать вебпаком все, чтобы инициализация происходила как во втором варианте?

Comment: несколько вариантов: не использовать вебпак, покопаться в настройках вебпака, попробовать сделать экспорт для модуля

Comment: если нашли ответ, допишите в вопрос, что ошибка после сборки вебпаком и в теги вебпак добавьте, чтобы помочь найти тему тем, кто столкнулся с такой же ошибкой

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n собственно этим и был занят

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось достаточно тривиальным, если обернуть конструктор в самовызывающуюся анонимную функцию и присвоить его внутри этой функции глобальному объекту `window`, то все прекрасно работает. Получается вот такая конструкция:

```
(function () {

function yourConstructor() {/* your code */};

window.yourConstructor = yourConstructor;

})();
```

Практика не самая лучшая, так как подобное использование глобальных переменных, методов или функций может легко создавать конфликты имен и ошибки в глобальном объекте. Но пока это единственный реально рабочий вариант, который мне удалось найти. Надеюсь дальнейшее изыскание приведет к более правильным и не менее рабочим ответам.

За идею спасибо отписавшимся в комменты.

Comment: Непонятно. По идее, объявление конструктора вне IIFE тоже приведет к определению его внутри `window`.

Comment: @smellyshovel, если в дело не вмешивается какой-нибудь сборщик

Comment: @Grundy а, ну может быть. С ними я почти не знаком.

Comment: @smellyshovel есть вполне реальное подозрение, что при сборке на webpack, свойство конструктора `[[Scope]]` ссылается не на `window`, а на текущий `LexicalEnvironment`, поэтому и не получалось получить к нему доступ.

Comment: @Илья при таком раскладе у вас бы вообще замыкания не работали. Более вероятно, что он в отдельные функции (со своими областями видимости, разумеется) ваш код сливает.

Comment: @Илья более того, `[[scope]]` и не всегда обязан именно на `window` ссылаться. Это еще зависит от того, как объявлен конструктор, и используется ли `strict mode`.